# Get % gain/ loss of BTC in the last 24 hour period - Coinbase

Tags: javascript, coinbase-api

I am looking to get the % change of the cryptocurrency Bitcoin vs USD.

Something similar to the way Coinbase works it out on their website (the red -10% for example):
[image: btc price vs usd]

I attempted to find this via the Coinbase API but wasn't able to.

Closest I got was this public endpoint:
`https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot`

But the response looks like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "base": "BTC",
        "currency": "USD",
        "amount": "31208.85"
    }
}
```

Does not have any metrics for the last 24 hours.

Perhaps I am looking in the wrong section but is this possible? Or do I have to calculate this % myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead look to the Coinbase Pro API, specifically [24 hour stats](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#get-24hr-stats).

```
GET https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USD/stats
```

Which gives you:

```json
{ 
  "open":"34977.48",
  "high":"35679.45",
  "low":"30150",
  "volume":"45646.70203384",
  "last":"30373.21",
  "volume_30day":"1027072.33957844"
}
```

From this you can calculate the percentage change, assuming the above is `data`:

```
> (data.last - data.open)/data.open*100
> -13.163526932186093
```